Network doesn't support eip-1559
This is the given genesis file. In this network every transaction works with the rpc connection as
const web3 = new Web3('http://146.190.XXX.XX:8546')

This rpc can do contract executions as well. And using metamask token generations and network coin transfers works as well. But when I try to do network coin transfer using the function claimFaucet() it throws an error

Network doesn't support eip-1559

claimFaucet = async function (toAddress, pKey) {
  // body...
    const myAddress = '0xaC7E9A085A5D13d5C38XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' //TODO: replace this address with your own public address
   
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress, 'latest');

    const transaction = {
     'to': toAddress, // faucet address to return eth
     'value': 10000000000000000,
     'gas': 426144,
     'maxFeePerGas': 10000000000,
     'nonce': nonce
    };
    console.log(nonce,transaction)
   
    const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction, pKey);
    
    await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction, function(error, hash){
      console.log(hash)
      return;
      
    });
}

{
"config": {
"chainId": 416,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0,
"eip1559Block": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"constantinopleBlock": 0,
"petersburgBlock": 0,
"istanbulBlock": 0
},
"alloc" : {
  "0xF58bCF53e07a4f85e872346Ce603D2269Cc5Bb67": {"balance":"510000000000000000000000000"},
  "0xa583Eb6b4c29e047996D03Db2CC86573E16233c6": {"balance":"800000000000000000000000000"}
},
"coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"difficulty" : "0x100000",
"extraData" : "",
"gasLimit" : "0x1000000",
"nonce" : "0x0000000000000042",
"mixhash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp" : "0x00"
}

Normal transfers working on metamask. Contract execution works on metamask and throught the rpc in web3 provider as well. But the code to send some faucet with the mentioned code base is not working.
